# Best way to reduce dictionary of lists

Tags: python

I am asking this question to get a starting point of the Pythonic way to reduce some of the list contents in the following dictionary using list comprehensions:

```
{'cycle1': [1, 2407, 2393, 14],
 'cycle2': [2, 1657, 1652, 5], 
 'cycle3': [3, 2698, 2673, 25], 
 'cycle4': [4, 2116, 2102, 14], 
 'cycle5': [5, 2065, 2048, 17], 
 'cycle6': [6, 1633, 1615, 18]}
```

Each list's columns, though not marked, have these headers:

```
section_num,account_total,billable_count,nonbillable_count
```

I want to sum each of the last three columns, account_total, billable_count, non-billable_count in a list comprehension.

I'm just not sure how to sum going through each list member in a comprehension. I need to ask for the values of each key, each value being a list. I'm just a little unsure about how to do that.

Comment: The Pythonic way is to have the dict contents be objects rather than lists...

Comment: Specific example? I basically thought I could represent cycle, and the remaining values as a list. What other method would I do? Python isn't forcing objects these days is it?

Comment: If I understand correctly you have 4 separate related values - `section_num`, `account_total`, `billable_count`, `nonbillable_count`.  In any programming language that looks like an object with 4 distinct fields, not a list.  Obviously you _can_ use a list but you have to document it, remember which list index is which field, etc - that might work but it makes maintenance harder, so I think it's bad style unless you have a very good reason that's not mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using `zip`?  This does an individual sum of each column, although I'm not sure that is what you want.

```
[sum(x) for x in zip(*my_dict.values())[1:]]
```

This outputs:

```
[12576, 12483, 93]
```

Comment: I'm a little confused. What does the '*' do in `*my_dict.values())`? Also, I'm getting this error in 2.7 [sum(x) for x in zip(*my_dict.values())[1:]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: It's a way to unpack all the arguments in your data structure.  See this link: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Comment: or see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/python-once-and-for-all-what-does-the-star-operator-mean-in-python for an explanation

Comment: @octopusgrabbus Odd, it works for me in 2.7.3.  Did you mix a variable name up or not copy it correctly by accident?

Answer (score 2):

a bit unclear about the output-format requested, but the line below sums the second column:

```
In [13]: c = {'cycle1': [1, 2407, 2393, 14],
 'cycle2': [2, 1657, 1652, 5], 
 'cycle3': [3, 2698, 2673, 25], 
 'cycle4': [4, 2116, 2102, 14], 
 'cycle5': [5, 2065, 2048, 17], 
 'cycle6': [6, 1633, 1615, 18]}

In [14]: sum([v[1] for k, v in c.iteritems()])
Out[14]: 12576
```

Using python3.3

```
>>> sum([v[1] for v in c.values()])
12576
```

Comment: I am basically looking to create a cycle -- let's call it cycle9 -- that ignores each list's 0th element and sums all element 1 values, all element 2 values, and all element 3 values.

Comment: ah, then you need the solution given by @squiguy

Comment: Also got this error: sum([v[1] for k, v in c.iteritems()])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: see updated example, works for me (tm) using 2.7. SLight modification needed for 3.3

Comment: Remove the `[]` square brackets inside `sum` to have a generator expression, which is more efficient,  instead of a list comprehension.